# Dynamic survey with Angular JS and asp.net

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am trying to build an application similar to survey monkey. I am planning to use AngularJS and Asp.net MVC. I have SurveyQuestion table in database which holds information about question text and type of control. Let's say for now if we have two rows in SurveyQuestion table indicating that there would be two Textbox questions on survey page. I want to load question text from database and based on question type show appropriate HTML control in UI(in this case it will be just two textboxes) using angular. I created angular controller for textbox and using ng-model I populated value in both textboxes, but if I change value in one textbox it is changing value in another textbox which I believe is the purpose of ng-model. Can you please advise how do I approach overhere.  I also need to save response from textbox to database when uses clicks out of textbox i.e on ng-blur event I want to save response to database.

Answer (score 0):

Set your directive to point to an MVC action that returns the view that correlates to the correct model.

something like /forms/vendor

and have it build the html the model, should look something like this in MVC

```
public class FormController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Vendor()
    {
        return View(new Vendor());
    }
}
```

The view will return an something simple like this

```
@model Agile.Core.Models.Vendor


@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Then wire up the EditorTemplate cshtml files to give you the values you want to render in angular like this

```
String.cshtml

@using Agile.Utilities.Extensions
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       required="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired"
       ng-model="@ViewData.GetModelName()"
       id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("").ToCamelCase()"
       name="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("").ToCamelCase()">
```

This is the general approach I would use

Comment: Is it possible to do completely with Angular with out using any of the razor views. I want to use MVC to load index.cshmtl with just header and footer.

Comment: you will need to use reflection at some point to extract the metadata from the c# models into something that your angular application could consume, so I think this is the easiest approach.